# When using curses.getkey() arrow keys return different values in command prompt and vscode integrated terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-curses

If I use a simple python script to check the value that is returned by the curses.getkey()

```py
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    input = stdscr.getkey()
    curses.endwin()
    print(input)

curses.wrapper(main)
```

I get different values for arrow keys on the vscode integrated terminal (cmd, not powershell) and command prompt. Command prompt gives `KEY_LEFT` for the left arrow key, while vscode gives `KEY_B1`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Some people have run across the same problem as you and submitted a bug on GitHub, but it was closed without a suitable solution. I recreated a new one on Github, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/16717).